# How to fix Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a js code (in `index.php`) as shown below which makes an ajax call to `save.php` file.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('form').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post({
                url: 'save.php',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
            }).done(response => {
                console.log(response);
                response = JSON.parse(response);
                if (response.message) {
                    alert(response.message);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The issue which I am facing right now with the code above is when we hit save button I am getting the following error message on the console:

```
VM68:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.php:1011)
    at c (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at l (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
```

Here `line#1011` is `response = JSON.parse(response);` from the js code above.

**Problem Statement**: I am wondering what changes I need to make in the js code above so that on hitting save button I do not get that error message on the console.

Comment: can you provide a sample response?

Comment: What type of data are you returning/echoing from save.php?

Comment: sample response ? Are you asking me to show the o/p of `console.log(response)`  ?

Comment: Yes. Did you expect that response to be a valid JSON string. Are you trying to handle an error in the event that it's not valid?

Comment: @CWB When it works, I get the following message on the console. `{"success":true,"message":"4308 bytes written to file."}`

Comment: Does my answer below resolve your issue?

Comment: @flash But what do you get in the console when it *doesn't* work?

Comment: @Kmoser Apologies for the delay in reply. I get the `login.php` code on the console. `login.php` code has some html and php codes inside it. Not sure why `login.php` code is coming on the console.

Comment: @flash Please show the contents of `save.php`.

Comment: here are my contents of `save.php` file https://3v4l.org/AlQB7

Comment: Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: @flash Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64084267/edit) to include relevant code, don't post it as a comment that links to an external site. Also, it looks like `save.php` is including `helpers.php`. Without seeing that code, there's not much we can do to help. You should really be posting a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), not just a few bits of code.

Answer (score 0):

If are aware of the error and just want to ignore it/handle it use a try/catch block. That error is usually because response isn't a valid json string so `JSON.parse` will keep failing.

```js
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post({
            url: 'save.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
        }).done(response => {
            try{
                response = JSON.parse(response);
                if (response.message) {
                    alert(response.message);
                }
            }
            catch (e) {
                //do something like alert user the request failed
                alert('Request to server failed');
            }

        });
    });
```

More on [try/catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) from mozilla.